# What files go in grails-app/assets versus web-app

Tags: grails

I am just getting started with Grails and trying to understand when to put files in `grails-app/assets/{stylesheets|images|javascript}` versus putting things in `web-app/{css|images|js}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, if you want your front-end resources to be managed by the [Asset Pipeline plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline), you should put them in `grails-app/assets`. If you don't, you should put them under `web-app`.

Comment: Thank you. The files are accessed using the <asset:{stylesheet:javascript:image} notation, correct?

How do I access those files in the web-app directory?
Does the AssetPipeline plugin mean that I don't need to use the <r:> notation for anything?

Comment: this is correct - assets from the asset path are references with <asset:... />. the <r:> tags come from the resource plugin, which was the default asset handling mecanism in pre grails 2.4 - in 2.4 it's asset pipeline. so depending on your grails version, you should use the corresponding plugin (the resource plugin could also be used in 2.4, but it is not the default one any more). asset-pipeline has support for the web-app folder as well (for legacy reasons, @see: http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html), so you can also access them via <asset:... />!

Comment: what is the go-forward approach... asset or web-app?  Im running Grails 2.4.4,  Thanks

Comment: the `asset-pipeline` plugin is the preferred approach